# Math/polynomials challenge: how to sort 13 enormous (approx. 200 terms each) polynomials, each having terms with 5 variables (1>h0>h1>h2>h3>h4)?

Tags: polynomials

Both manually or with software (numerically, for example) is acceptable. Here is a how one of the polynomials looks like ($L<1$ is a constant).
I have attached a text file with all the 13 polynomials that I need to sort in ascending order - more precisely, I have a target order I need to achieve, so I need to define the ranges of the variables h0-h4 where that order would be valid. Here is one representative polynomial sample:
$7*h_0*h_1^2*h_2^2*h_3*L^3 + 29*h_0*h_1^2*h_2^2*h_3*h4^2*L^4 + 3*h_0*h2^2*h_4*L^2 + 5*h0*h2^2*h4^3*L^3 +...$ each polynomial has approximately 200 terms(!).

Comment: What do you mean to sort?

Comment: Finding the complete ranges is likely computationally infeasible, but it might be possible to find specific values.

Comment: Dear mathreadler, these polynomials are the algebraic results of 13 outputs of an artificial neural network, which models a certain biological process. Experimental evidence gives the actual order of those 13 values (outputs). I need to find the constraints/ranges/conditions that h0, h1, h2, h3 and h4 should fulfill )on top of 1>h0>h1>h2>h3>h4>0, in order to obtain the proper order of the (values of the) 13 polynomials.

Comment: I was thinking to try a numerical method (to calculate the values of these 13 polynomials) for different sets (combinations...  a lot of them) of h0-h4 values, so I could possibly find the ranges. My (additional) problem there would be to find the necessary precision that I should use, so I won't miss any distinct range (since the real numbers set is dense).